# What does this \begin{document} error mean?

Tags: debugging

Code

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{caption}; 
\usepackage{longtable}; 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
Discussion.

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
\caption{People and their roles in the lab.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
People in lab
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Roles
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
People in lab
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Roles
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Masi wk 1.
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Gems
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Henri
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
 present
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Pena
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
construction
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

which gives the error about missing `\begin{document}` which does not make sense to me.

[image]

and Pandoc table where same defects in the first line

[image]

Logs

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99991 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.11.23)  23 MAY 2015 12:07
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2014/05/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
Package: caption 2013/05/02 v3.3-89 Customizing captions (AR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
Package: caption3 2013/05/02 v1.6-88 caption3 kernel (AR)
Package caption3 Info: TeX engine: e-TeX on input line 57.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
\captionmargin=\dimen103
\captionmargin@=\dimen104
\captionwidth=\dimen105
\caption@tempdima=\dimen106
\caption@indent=\dimen107
\caption@parindent=\dimen108
\caption@hangindent=\dimen109
)
\c@ContinuedFloat=\count88
)

./test.tex:3: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \usepackage{caption};

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2014/10/28 v4.11 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip43
\LTright=\skip44
\LTpre=\skip45
\LTpost=\skip46
\LTchunksize=\count89
\LTcapwidth=\dimen110
\LT@head=\box26
\LT@firsthead=\box27
\LT@foot=\box28
\LT@lastfoot=\box29
\LT@cols=\count90
\LT@rows=\count91
\c@LT@tables=\count92
\c@LT@chunks=\count93
\LT@p@ftn=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty
Package: booktabs 2005/04/14 v1.61803 publication quality tables
\heavyrulewidth=\dimen111
\lightrulewidth=\dimen112
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen113
\belowrulesep=\dimen114
\belowbottomsep=\dimen115
\aboverulesep=\dimen116
\abovetopsep=\dimen117
\cmidrulesep=\dimen118
\cmidrulekern=\dimen119
\defaultaddspace=\dimen120
\@cmidla=\count94
\@cmidlb=\count95
\@aboverulesep=\dimen121
\@belowrulesep=\dimen122
\@thisruleclass=\count96
\@lastruleclass=\count97
\@thisrulewidth=\dimen123
)
(./test.aux)
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 6.
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: longtable package is loaded.

(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/ltcaption.sty
Package: ltcaption 2013/02/03 v1.3-62 longtable captions (AR)
)
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
 [1

]
(./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1455 strings out of 493724
 23935 string characters out of 6145898
 84695 words of memory out of 5000000
 4848 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 36i,9n,44p,206b,324s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on test.pdf (1 page).
```

What does the error about missing `\begin{document}` mean here?

Why do you get the defect in the first line?

Comment: The `;` after the `\usepackage{caption}` and `\usepackage{booktabs}` are wrong, I assume. LaTeX tries to typeset `;` then, before `\begin{document}`, which is an error.

Comment: You are right! My bad mistake. I wrote them originally as one-liner and did not recognize to remove the semicolorns like `\usepackage{caption}; \usepackage{longtable}; \usepackage{booktabs}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is `;` after the `\usepackage{...}` statements, but I have no idea how this can be prevented in `pandoc` if there is some automatic generation

If LaTeX encounters typesetting material (such as text, interpunctuation characters) in the preamble it will issue the error message `missing document`, since this content is not allowed in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{caption}  % Removed the ; here
\usepackage{longtable} % and removed ; here
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
Discussion.

\begin{longtable}[c]{@{}ll@{}}
\caption{People and their roles in the lab.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
People in lab
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Roles
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
People in lab
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Roles
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Masi wk 1.
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Gems
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Henri
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
 present
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.37\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
Pena
\strut\end{minipage} &
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\columnwidth}\raggedright\strut
construction
\strut\end{minipage}\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```